# Background as a guide, fixed. Resizing

Tags: php, html, css

I am writing a simple entry page for a organization, this is the preview +/- of the intended final product. http://i2.minus.com/iBZ0KfRGGVVch.jpg

My current work, http://komayo.no-ip.org:8888/Entry/public/

But i am having some problems, issue is resizing the browser window, everything moves from place having the background as a guide to positions. How can i fix this? Iam using a wrapper at center, 1280px width to organize the divs, menus in place, using the background as a reference, background has the areas where the blocks will be. Iam positioning everything over.

Comment: All the code, http://jsfiddle.net/4v8F7/

Comment: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/ read this

Comment: That helped me a bit with the positioning of elements using %, but iam a bit lost with the resize stuff. Is there other solutions? Maybe better not use the background image, as a reference to position stuff. Iam lost

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you :(. I'm no expert at this myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed!

Jonan thanks for sharing that reading, it helped a lot with the positioning of elements, after i fixed the issue. And it helped a bit on resolving the issue, at least to find a workaround. :).

I managed to fix the issue, by spliting the background in 3 sub images, header, main and footer, that way i never had a break on the resizing of browser! :)

Thank you.